# How to Transform Any graph using Complex Function (like we did for Linear Transformation)?

Tags: manim

How can I tranform a graph or the whole Number plane using Complex Function?, Like suppose I have `f(z)=z^2 =(x^2-y^2)+i(2xy)`, Now we have `U=x^2-y^2` and `V=2xy` , 
I am saying that I want to show the transformation X to U and Y to V, 
I know the Linear Transformation but how to apply the complex Transformation when we have 2 different Functions?
And it would be helpful if you can also show how to plot in complex plane?
Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the example_scenes.py, in `WarpSquare` scene.

```py
class ComplexTransformation(LinearTransformationScene):
    def construct(self):
        square = Square().scale(2)
        function = lambda point: complex_to_R3(R3_to_complex(point)**2)

        self.add_transformable_mobject(square)

        self.apply_nonlinear_transformation(function)

        self.wait()
```

Comment: What does complex_to_R3 ? And is the basis vector appears automatically?

Comment: This scene can apply a function to the grid, but only in a **R^2** or **R^3** vector space, so you must convert the **R^2** space into a **C** space. `R3_to_complex` converts an **R^3** coordinate to the complex field. Then `complex_to_R3` converts the complex space to **R^3**.